# How to send input to c++ through python

Tags: python, c++

I have used the following code to pass input to cpp program which reads input and prints it.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['a.exe'], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
for ii in range(10):
    value = str(ii) + '\n'
    value = bytes(value, 'UTF-8')  # Needed in Python 3.
    p.stdin.write(value)
    #p.stdin.flush()
    result = p.stdout.readline().strip()
    print(result)
```

Following was the output of python

```
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
b''
```

EDIT:
Following is the code for cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
        cout<<a[i];
        std::cout.flush();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: what is `a.exe` ? Maybe it returns empty string.

Comment: Output is not correct.

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried code on Linux and I had two problems

- in Python I had to use full path to `a.exe` to run it
- in CPP I had to add `<< '\n'` because it sends text without `\n` and `p.stdout.readline()` is waiting for `\n`

Without full path I saw many `b''` (and message `"... not found"` in first line)

Without `<< '\n'` script freezed because `readline()` was waiting for `\n`

---

**EDIT:** I forgot: I had to add `p.stdin.flush()`.

---

**EDIT:** as @Sugar suggested in comment - use `std::endl` instead of `"\n"`

Comment: on windows even with end of line output it still locks up.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre try with `p.stdin.flush()`

Comment: good work. I had tried that but without the newline on the C++ side. After that, I tried newline, but without the stdin flush :) You should never flush stdin, that's true, but in our case `stdin` is an output file from python side.

Comment: don't use `\n` for `std::cout`. use `std::endl` instead